# IP Cam to Gtalk

Tags: c#, video-streaming, rtsp, google-talk

I am looking for working ideas and tips on how to forward IP camera's video feed into Google talk.

Here is a C# method skeleton on what I want to do:

```
/// <summary>
/// This method makes it possible to use a IP-cam instead of a web-cam for GTalk
/// </summary>
/// <param name="UrlIPCam">URL to the IP camera (rtsp)</param>
/// <param name="UsrGoogleAccount">Username Google account</param>
/// <param name="PwdGoogleAccount">Password Google account</param>
private void StreamIPCamToGTalk(string UrlIPCam, string UsrGoogleAccount, string PwdGoogleAccount)
{

}
```

where for example

- UrlIPCam = "rtsp://ip_adx/live.sdp" (H264)
- UsrGoogleAccount = "donny.lonny12345"
- PwdGoogleAccount = "1onnydoNnyl23456"

C#/VB.NET (and possible C++ .NET-wrappers) is mandatory. Is this possible?

Comment: Is it going to be automatic, or you want to be able to pick the IP camera as a video source for GTalk client on Windows (or, GMail web interface).

Comment: Well, actually I am not trying to re-invent the wheel and develop a standard jabberclient.

Comment: You are trying to develop another jabber client, or you are trying to add video capability to existing client?

Comment: Well, it is not the jabber client in it self (at least not the messaging part) that I'm intrested in, more the technique. My goal is to feed video streams from IP-cameras through "evil" firewalls. 

Since this works very well with standard web cams and GTalk, I think I could use the same technique for IP cameras video feed?

Comment: So you actually have completely different question? Your camera streams via `RTP`, which is most likely using `UDP` underneath. And this is the reason why it does not go through a firewall. What you need is to takes this feed and re-stream usign custom or well known `TCP` or even `HTTP` based protocol. It has tothing to do with Google Talk and Jabber.

Comment: I do not agree that it is an entirely different issue.
Why? -I _know_ that the technique works when using a web cam and a computer in regular chat sessions.

In the end, I need bidirectional communication between an IP camera (server) and an arbitrary user (any system) without risking being impeded by firewalls. It may not matter if it's IP camera (server) or an arbitrary user who initiates the connection. I know that this works with a standard jabber client.

Comment: You have a problem with IP camera and firewall for a reason. And Jabber is one of the protocols among many which works the problem around.

Comment: Excatly. Thanks anyway for your great tip (and answer down below)! :o)

Answer (score 3):

Applications pick up cameras by listing available DirectShow video sources, more specifically - `CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory`. To add a device there, you need to install a driver that implements such device or develop your own. There are good and well known samples to start from, though most likely you cannot do it in C# only, and it will require C++.

You can use my [source filter to take video from JPEG and M-JPEG IP cameras](http://alax.info/blog/1216) and to expose it as a virtual device, it works with GTalk plugin hosted by GMail.

[image]

See:

- [CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory and Selecting a Capture Device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377566%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Push Source Filters Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [How to Write a Source Filter for DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757807%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [DirectShow Video Source Filter for JPEG and M-JPEG IP Cameras](http://alax.info/blog/1216)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I'm too junior (my reputation is below 15) to vote it up for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the options to [embed FreeSWITCH](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Embedding_FreeSWITCH) into C# applications. I believe it is capable of handling RTSP video streams (if not it should be possible to write a module to handle it) and I know it supports jabber/gtalk as a gateway. It is by no means a small task, but should be doable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I'm too junior (my reputation is below 15) to vote it up for the moment.